# Trying to get counts through multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, associations

I have created a question an answer app for a client much like StackOverflow. I am not trying to implement some sort of point system (like SO reputation). I am trying to get certain record counts through associations (which I believe are set up correctly). Primarily I am trying to get counts for votes on users answers. Here is an example.

In `/views/questions/show` page I list all the answers to that question by calling a partial `_answer.html.erb`. With each answer I pull in the answer.user information (username, email, etc.) by simply doing `answer.user.username`. I am wanting to display in a badge like format some total point calculations. So if `User A` answered `Question A`, next to `User A`'s answer I want to display a total of all `User A`'s answer votes.

I can successfully get a count for a users answers in /views/answers/_answer.html.erb by doing the following:

```
<%= answer.user.answers.count %>
```

but when I try to extend that syntax/association to get a count of votes on all `User A`'s answers I get undefined method errors.

```
<%= answer.user.answers.votes.count %>
```

Is my set up fundamentally wrong here or am I missing something.

That is a bit confusing so let me know if you need more detail.

UPDATE:

Here are the associations:

Answers

```
class Answer < ActivRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Votes

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Users

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :votes, :through => :answers , :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= answer.user.answers.votes.count %>
```

but

```
answer.user.answers
```

is an array of answers so I suppose you wanted something like

```
<%= answer.user.answers[id].votes.count %>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<% answer.user.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <%= answer.votes.count%>
<% end% >
```

**UPDATE**

```
 <%= (answer.user.answers.map{|x| x.votes.count}).sum%>
```

I LOVE rails for such things

Comment: I might should have mentioned that I am in Rails 2.3.9

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't see you updated the code. This loop doesn't cause errors. Just outputs multiple records and I really want the sum of that.

Answer (score 1):

*but when I try to extend that syntax/association to get a count of votes on all User A's answers I get undefined method errors.*
You can find complete listing of what you can do with `user.answers` collection [in here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) (besides standard Array/Enumerable methods). And it's only collection instance, not `Answer` object, so you can't invoke methods from `Answer` model on it.

You can try setupping `has_many :votes, :through => :answers` relationship. ([See here for details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)) Although, I'm not sure if `:through` would work in such case.
Alternatively, you can create a method in `User` model to return all `Vote` objects (simply by iterating through all answers)

But frankly, creating a horde of `Vote` objects simply to count them sounds like a terrible waste of resources to me.

Comment: So, what are you saying is the answer here? If it's not to create the Vote objects, and it can't be done through the other methods you mention...what should I do?

Comment: I didn't say it can't be done. E.g., you can always add custom method to the `User` model and sum everything in a loop (like **Bohdan Pohorilets** mentioned in his post). But simpler solution would be just to save reputation value for each user in database (you can leave or remove `Vote` model). Then, when somebody votes, you need to update it.

Comment: Are you saying to create a reputation table and then on something like votes, in the Vote model use an after_create to update the reputation table?

Comment: @bgadoci Or create integer column in `users` table, holding reputation. after_create (or other event handlers) sounds like a good idea too.

Comment: Nikita's right you need Votes model only if you have additional values in votes table except count of votes